# Uncaught OAuth Exception - api('/me','GET') not functioning in Safari

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have an app that runs from a Page tab. Logging in to the app is done via Javascript.

```
function facebooklogin() {
   FB.getLoginStatus(function (response) {
      if (response.status === 'connected') {
         //user authorized
         //SubmitLogin(response);
         fbid = response.authResponse.userID; //valid response returned
         token = response.authResponse.accessToken; //valid response returned
         SubmitLogin();
      }
      else if (response.status === 'not_authorized') {
         FB.login(function (response) {
            if (response.authResponse) {
               // user authorized
               //SubmitLogin(response);
               fbid = response.authResponse.userID; //valid response returned
               token = response.authResponse.accessToken; //valid response returned
               SubmitLogin();
            } else {
               // user cancelled
               alert("User authorization is required for taking part in this promo.");
            }
         }, {
            scope: 'user_about_me,user_birthday,user_checkins,user_hometown,user_location,publish_stream,email'
         });
      } else {
      // the user isn't logged in to Facebook.
      }
   });
}

function SubmitLogin() {
   //$("#token").val(response.authResponse.accessToken);
   //$("#fbid").val(response.authResponse.userID);
   //$("#login_form").submit();
   $("#print_me").prop("href", "printable.php?fbid=" + fbid);
   if (fbid != "") {
      $.post("submit_user.php", "fbid=" + fbid + "&token=" + token, function(msg) {
         var spl = msg.split("|");

         if (spl.length == 3) {
            //this part isn't an issue since the code never reaches it
            post_wall();
            $("#share_section").css({display: "none"});
            $("#reward_section").css({display: "block"});
            FB.Canvas.setSize();

            $("#coupon_printout").html(spl[0]);
            $("#qr_holder").html(spl[1]);
            $("#expiration").html(spl[2]);
         }
         else {
            //code always lands here because of the error in the php script
            alert(msg);
         }
      });
   }
   else {
      alert("You have not signed in to this app. If you did not see a sign in request, you may need to disable your pop-up blocker.");
   }
}
```

When I echo the return values, the user's FacebookID and Access Token come back correct. I then pass these to a PHP script that signs in to the app. Everything works fine up to this point.

```
require 'facebook.php';
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
'appId' => /*my app ID*/,
'secret' => /*my app secret*/,
'cookie' => true
));

$signedRequest = $facebook->getSignedRequest(); //is blank

$user_id = $facebook->getUser(); //user's FacebookID gets returned
$user_profile = $facebook->api('/me','GET'); //OAuth error gets thrown
```

This is the entirety of my PHP code until the part where the OAuth error gets thrown when on Safari. I've tried printing out the access token I passed via post and it appears. getAccessToken() prints out a different value, however.

No errors have occurred in other browsers in this area.

edit:
moved the files to a different server and it started working for some browsers while having no difference in others.

Comment: _“getAccessToken() prints out a different value, however.”_ – obviously not a good sign. Try passing your “other” access token explicitly when making the API call.

Comment: to make things more complicated, getAccessToken() prints out a value that doesn't even look like an access token. I get a 15 digit number instead of that ridiculously long alphanumeric string. for added fun, not all versions of Safari do this.